# Integrate soundcloud music but reskin the player?

Tags: soundcloud, skin

I'd like to link people to soundcloud music / embedded files but reskin the player to have a custom feel. Is this possible? Or allowed rather.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that.

- build your own player using their API
- use the JS SDK -> embedding features
- they have a jquery plugin (which looks like not maintained anymore or merged into the JS SDK now)

Links:

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#embedding
http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#oEmbed

https://github.com/soundcloud/Widget-JS-API

http://stratus.sc

https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-custom-player